# mongodb upgrade 2.6.3 to 2.6.4 lost databases

Tags: mongodb

OK, I just began using Mongodb. I've gone through a course. Creating 2 databases with collections. Data was there after a reboot. But, tonight, I performed a very minor upgade from 2.6.3 to 2.6.4 and subsequenty lost the likage to my databases. The file structure stayed the same, so I didn't hink anything of it, until I noticed everything I had done, including adding a collection to test, was gone. I attempted a repair after the fact but it had no impact on recovering the data. Fortunately, I had gone through the trouble of exporting all my data as well as backing t up beforehand. I imported my data and all is good. But I'm not sure why Mongod lost the references to all my data? Especially for such a minor upgrade and no changes to the paths.

Comment: How did you upgrade?

Comment: Going to shut you down right now. This is not a programming question. StackOverflow is for "programming questions". Ask on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) instead. Anyone who attempts to answer here gets downvoted. So migrate your question yourself. You are a member already by signing up to this site. Happy to talk to you there, but here you're in the wrong place.

Comment: Yeah, you guys can have a reputation for being somewhat rude at times to people genuinely seeking guidance. I understand the there needs to be structure, and that's cool. I get it now, but, there are an infinite ways to respond. Personally, I am not interested in trying to win a popularity contest with the voting. I simply am trying to learn a variety of technology skills outside the box I've been in, and having much fun doing so. But this "Going to have to shut you down" is a bit arrogant...     But in any case, thanks...